# Normal Gauss map and isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X:U\to\mathbb{R^3}$ be an oriented surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $N:U\to\mathbb{S}^2$ be its unit normal vector field. Consider $A\in O(3)$ an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let be $X'=A\circ X:U\to\mathbb{R}^3$ with unit normal vector field $N':U \to\mathbb{R}^3$.

My question is: How relate $N$ and $N'$?

Using the definition of normal vector and that $A\in O(3)$, I found that $N'=(\det A)AN$. However, if I define $B=(\det A)A$ then $B\in SO(3)$ and therefore $(X_u,X_v, N)$ and $(X'_u,X'_v, N')$ has always the same orientation, is it right?

My point is, even though $A\in O(3)$ is a reverse-orientation isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $(X_u,X_v, N)$ and $(X'_u,X'_v, N')$ are always positive basis? Is there some problem with the formula $N'=(\det A)AN$? I have a problem with orientation, I guess.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you define $N$? If you are using the cross product of $X_u$ and $X_v$, then $X_u, X_v, N$ will be always positively oriented.

Comment: @Thomas is by the cross product. If $(X_u,X_v,N)$ and if the formula is correct, this means that I can not change the orientation of the surface $X(U)$ using $A\in O(3)$?

Comment: You can change the orientation that way (take the $x_1, x_2$ plane in three space and reflect it across the $x_2$ axis), but not the property of being (not) orientable.